# Search in Laravel voyager related table

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, voyager

There is 2 table for managing categories one for parents and another for sub-categories. When I want to search with this associated field, I can't. and get this error

[Error description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T7WDb.png)

1. Hizmetler Model (**Sub-category**):

```
    class Hizmetler extends Model
    {
        protected $primaryKey = 'hizmet_id';
        protected $table = 'hizmetler';
        public $incrementing = false;
    
        use SoftDeletes;
        protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];
        public function Hizmetler(){
            return $this->belongsTo(Hizmetler::class,'hizmet_ust_kategori');
        }
    }
```

2. UstKategori Model (**Parent category**):

```
    class UstKategori extends Model
    {
        protected $primaryKey = 'id';
        protected $table = 'ust_kategori';
        public $incrementing = false;
    
        use SoftDeletes;
        protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];
        public function UstKategori(){
            return $this->hasOne(UstKategori::class);
        }
    }
```

[Category Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hUsiR.png)
[Sub Categroy Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gp10n.png)

Comment: Please share your model relationship functions.

Comment: i updated @A.Seddighi

Comment: Is your relation type between category and subcategory one to one? or it's one to many (one category has many sub category)

Comment: one category has many sub category

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your relationship is incorrect. according to your case, the relationship between the categories and their child is **One to Many**.

Parent Model:

```
class UstKategori extends Model
{
    public function childs(){
        return $this->hasMany(Hizmetler::class, 'hizmet_ust_kategori');
    }
}
```

Child Model:

```
class Hizmetler extends Model
{
    public function parent(){
        return $this->belongsTo(UstKategori::class, 'hizmet_ust_kategori');
    }
}
```

You can read the documentation and examples here: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many

Comment: Also, you don't need to create a new model for sub-categories if the columns are the same, you can make the relationship in the current model by adding the foreign key.

Comment: i get the same error when i change the model as you said, Do I need to operate on the bread, is the relationship type correct?  `Belongs To`

Comment: What is your error message? did you read the documentation and re-write your models?

Comment: yes, I do everything as you said, I get the error that the column I asked in the above question could not be found. Maybe you can check her twitter account.

Comment: Please share your migration of the tables

Comment: I updated the topic, I shared the tables

Comment: is the error message exacly the same?

Comment: yes the error message is the same

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by customizing the index method in VoyagerBaseController and copying the method to my controller.
The work steps are as follows.

1- Copy the public function index to your controller

2- Replacing search commands. These commands are inside the
conditional command if ($search->value != '' && $search->key && $search->filter).

3- Remove the above evil content and replace it with the following content:

```
        if ($search->value != '' && $search->key && $search->filter) {
            if ($search->key == 'model_id' || $search->key == 'color_id')
                $query->where($search->key, $search->value);
            else if ($search->key == 'image_belongsto_color_relationship') {
                $query->whereHas('color', function ($query) use ($search) {
                    if ($search->filter == 'equals') {
                        $query->where('title', $search->value);
                    } else {
                        $query->where('title', 'LIKE', '%' . $search->value . '%');
                    }
                });
            } 
        }
```

**Note: Don't forget to define the relationship in the desired model. For the example above, it is defined as follows:**

```
class Images extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    public function color(): BelongsTo
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Color::class, 'color_id');
    }
}
```

**don't forget the definition of the relationship in Bread Voyager. My relationship is defined as belongTo type.**

Answer (score 0):

Now Just **replace** the table name **"downloads"** to your own table. Which you can get from **yourwebsite.com/admin/database.**

**Where to Add:-**
Go to your project directory "vendor/tcg/voyager/resources/views/bread/ browse.blade.php.

FYI: Please make sure you replace the "download" in below table href with your own table to work.

If you don't want to edit this global template then move it to resources/vendor/voyager/yourbreadname/browse.blade.php

```html
<?php
$results = [];
$searchPerformed = false;
if (isset($_GET['search']) && !empty($_GET['search'])) {
    $search = $_GET['search'];
    $results = DB::table('downloads')->where('title', 'LIKE', "%$search%")->get();
    $searchPerformed = true;  // Indicate that a search was executed
}
?>
              
<style>
    .search-container {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        margin: 20px 0;
    }
    
    .search-bar {
        flex: 1;
        padding: 10px 20px;
        border-radius: 25px;
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
        outline: none;
        transition: border 0.3s;
    }
    
    .search-bar:focus {
        border: 1px solid #007bff; /* This will change border color to blue when the input is focused */
    }
    
    .search-button {
        margin-left: 10px;
        padding: 10px 20px;
        background-color: #007bff;
        color: white;
        border: none;
        border-radius: 25px;
        cursor: pointer;
        transition: background-color 0.3s;
    }
    
    .search-button:hover {
        background-color: #0056b3;
    }
</style>

<div class="search-container">
    <form method="GET" action="" style="display: flex; width: 100%; max-width: 1200px;">
        <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search by title" value="{{ request('search') }}" class="search-bar">
        <button type="submit" class="search-button">Search</button>
    </form>
</div>



@if($searchPerformed)  <!-- Add this conditional statement -->
<div class="panel panel-bordered">
    <div class="panel-body table-responsive">
        <table id="dataTable" class="row table table-hover">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Title</th>
                    <th>Image</th>
                    <th class="actions">Actions</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @if(count($results) > 0)
                    @foreach($results as $result)
                        <tr>
                            <td>{{ $result->title }}</td>
                            <td>
                                <!-- Display the image -->
                                <img src="{{ url('storage/' . $result->image) }}" alt="{{ $result->title }}" width="100">
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <!-- View using the slug -->
                                <a href="{{ url('download/' . $result->slug) }}" target="_blank" class="btn btn-sm btn-warning"><i class="voyager-eye"></i> View</a>
                                <a href="{{ url('admin/downloads/' . $result->id . '/edit') }}" target="_blank" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary edit"><i class="voyager-edit"></i> Edit</a>
                                @if (Voyager::can('delete_downloads'))
                                    <a href="javascript:;" title="Delete" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger delete" data-id="{{ $result->id }}" id="delete-{{ $result->id }}">
                                        <i class="voyager-trash"></i> <span class="hidden-xs hidden-sm">Delete</span>
                                    </a>
                                @endif
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    @endforeach
                @else
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="3">No results found</td>
                    </tr>
                @endif
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
@endif  <!-- End of the conditional statement -->

<script>
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        const deleteButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.delete');

        deleteButtons.forEach(button => {
            button.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
                const id = e.target.getAttribute('data-id');
                
  
                    // Send DELETE request
                    fetch(`admin/downloads/${id}`, {
                        method: 'DELETE',
                        headers: {
                            'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
                            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': '{{ csrf_token() }}'
                        }
                    });
          
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```